# Build summary table from matrix

Tags: r

I have this matrix

```
mdat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1), nrow = 4, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    1    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1    0    1
```

and I'm trying to build T:

```
     T1 T2 T3
row1  1  2  4
row2  2  2  3
row3  2  5  5
row4  3  1  3
row5  3  5  5
row6  4  1  3
row7  4  5  5
```

where for each row in mdat:
T1 shows mdat row number
T2  shows mdat column where there's the first 1 
T3  shows mdat column where there's the last consecutive 1.

Therefore

row1 in T is [1 2 4] because for row 1 in mdat the first 1 is in column 2 and the last consecutive 1 is in column 4.

row2 in T is [2 2 3] because for row 2 in mdat the first 1 is in column 2 and the last consecutive 1 is in column 3.

This is my try:

```
for (i in 1:4){ 
 for (j in 1:5) {

   if (mdat[i,j]==1) {T[i,1]<-i;T[i,2]<-j;
cont<-0;
while (mdat[i,j+cont]==1){
    cont<-cont+1;
    T[i,3]<-cont}
}
}
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325146/find-5-consecutive-numbers-3-for-each-row-of-a-matrix

Comment: `apply(mdat, 1, rle)` might be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a strategy using `apply/rle` as Richard suggested.

```
xx<-apply(mdat, 1, function(x) {
    r <- rle(x)
    w <- which(r$values==1)
    l <- r$lengths[w]
    s <- cumsum(c(0,r$lengths))[w]+1
    cbind(start=s,stop=s+l-1)
})
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, row=seq_along(xx), xx))
```

We start by finding the runs of 1 on each row using the "values" property of the `rle` and we calculate their start and stop positions using the "lengths" property. We turn this data into a list of two column matrices with one list item per row of the original matrix.

Now we use Map to add the row number back onto the matrix and then we rbind all the results. That seems to give you the data you're after

```
     row start stop
[1,]   1     2    4
[2,]   2     2    3
[3,]   2     5    5
[4,]   3     1    3
[5,]   3     5    5
[6,]   4     1    3
[7,]   4     5    5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the Bioconductor IRanges package:

```
library(IRanges)
r <- unlist(slice(split(Rle(mdat), row(mdat)), 1, rangesOnly=TRUE)))
r

IRanges of length 7
    start end width names
[1]     2   4     3     1
[2]     2   3     2     2
[3]     5   5     1     2
[4]     1   3     3     3
[5]     5   5     1     3
[6]     1   3     3     4
[7]     5   5     1     4
```

EDIT: optimized