# rle for finding rectangles in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm following this approach to find rectangles of 1's  in a (0,1) matrix

[Find 5 consecutive numbers >= 3 for each row of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325146/find-5-consecutive-numbers-3-for-each-row-of-a-matrix)

but there's a problem when I try to find 1x4 rectangles (1 row and 4 columns) like in this matrix

```
m <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0), nrow = 6, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
```

There are four rectangles: 1st row, 4th row, 5th row and 6th row

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1    0
[4,]    1    1    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    1    1    1
[6,]    1    1    1    1    0
```

when I run the code for this case I get the 4 results, but two of them (4th and 6th row) both results start at first column but in the result I get as starting column the 5th and ending column the 8th when the matrix is 6x5 and can't find out which is the problem.

```
b<-m

for (j in 1:5){
cont<-1
 for (i in 6:1) {
 if (m[i,j]==0){
cont<-1
b[i,j]<-NA}
 else {b[i,j]<-cont
cont<-cont+1}
}
}


mdat<-b

apply(mdat, 1, function(x) {
  r <- rle(x >= 1)
  w <- which(!is.na(r$values) & r$values & r$lengths >=4)
  if (length(w) > 0) {
    before <- sum(r$lengths[1:(w[1]-1)])
    c(before+1,before+ r$lengths[w[1]])
  } else
    NULL
})

[[1]]
[1] 2 5

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
[1] 5 8

[[5]]
[1] 2 5

[[6]]
[1] 5 8
```

Comment: What do you define as "rectangles"? You mean 4 consecutive `1`'s in a single row?

Comment: Yes, for me it is a 1x4 rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the calculation of `before` variable since it does not work if the row starts with the sequence of 1's :

```
apply(mdat, 1, function(x) {
  r <- rle(x >= 1)
  w <- which(!is.na(r$values) & r$values & r$lengths >=4)
  if (length(w) > 0) {
    before <- sum(r$lengths[1:w[1]]) - r$lengths[w[1]]
    c(before+1,before+r$lengths[w[1]])
  } else
    NULL
})
```

Problem was the following line :

```
before <- sum(r$lengths[1:(w[1]-1)])
```

that works properly only if the sequence of ones is not at the first position (i.e. w > 1).

BTW, note that your code only consider the first sequence in the row, ignoring other sequences (if present).
e.g. supposing to have one matrix `row = c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)`, it will return only `c(2,5)` and not `c(2,5), c(7,10)`

If you want something returning all the sequences, you can use this code :

```
apply(mdat, 1, function(x) {
  r <- rle(x >= 1)
  w <- which(!is.na(r$values) & r$values & r$lengths >=4)
  if (length(w) > 0) {
    lapply(w,FUN=function(w1){ before <- sum(r$lengths[1:w1]) - r$lengths[w1];
                               c(before+1,before+r$lengths[w1]) })
  } else
    NULL
})
```

N.B. it returns a list where each element is a list containing the pairs

Comment: Thanks so much!! If instead of finding sequences in rows I try to find them in columns, for example in the matrix above there are 6 consecutive 1's in the fourth column, I'm using the same mdat matrix and the same code but changing the >= conditions is not enough

Comment: Well there is an easy "hack" i.e. passing the transposed matrix to the apply (just do t(mdat) to get the transposed). But if you want to change the code properly to work on the columns, change the second argument passed to apply from 1 to 2 (1 means "for each row apply the function", 2 means "for each row apply the function")

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed a stupid copy&paste error... obviously it is : *1 means "for each row apply the function", 2 means "for each column apply the function"*. But I think you understood anyway :)